# initializing Arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and am struggling to figure out how to initialize an array of unicode chars to a certain size. I want to use arrays not lists as I desire O(1) random access and O(1) amortized cost for insertion. So far I have this:

```
from arrays import *
a = array('u')
```

but obviously this is a zero length array.

Thanks,
Aly

Comment: Lists offer O(1) random access and armotized O(1) append (see the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)). Arrays don't offer anything over that (they only shave off constant factors), and may even be worse for appending. Both arrays and lists require copying elements when inserting (adding a new item, not overwriting an existing one) in the middle of the sequence. I'm not aware of any data structure that offers worst-case O(1) access (has tables are armotized O(1)) and armotized O(1) insertion *everywhere*. Please clarify.

Comment: it always wondered me, why python does not have a standard way of doing this, same for normal lists. I usually go with [None]*100 or similar.

Comment: @delnan I dont mind using lists tbh given that I have now been made aware that they are just like Java ArrayLists, I am implementing a gap buffer so doubling the list and doing coppies myself is useful rather than just appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a new array initialized to `"unicode string"`.

```
from array import *
a = array('u', u"unicode string")
```

If you only want it initialized to a certain size, you can do this:

```
a = array('u', u'\0' * size)
```

This will initialize a unicode character array with size `size` initialized to null characters.

Comment: This is the first thing i thought of too, but I still find it to be quite uneasy on the eyes. You need to allocate the length of the array of dummy values for them to be copied. While this is a constant factor, it is still unnecessary.

Comment: array.array('u', (u'\0' for _ in xrange(100))) via a generator expression works too, but I still have the feeling, that the module internally is just doing an append operation for every item.